# Traducción al español de "Relatable"

Tags: traducción

Me gustaría conocer la traducción de la palabra inglesa **relatable**.

La definición es la siguiente:

> **that someone can understand or feel sympathy for:**
>
> *If you've ever really listened to Colbie Caillat lyrics, then you know they are simple, yet extremely relatable.*
>
> *One of the reasons for her success is that the characters in her books are so relatable.*

Entiendo que quiere decir que es fácil identificarse con ello, pero me preguntaba si habría alguna palabra equivalente en español.

Comment: Yo en ese ejemplo usaría *cercano*: *Si alguna vez realmente has escuchado las letras de Colbie Caillat, entonces sabes que son simples, pero extremadamente cercanas.*

Comment: Yo personalmente preferiría que incluyeras en la pregunta la definición inglesa de "relatable", dado que sinceramente no entiendo lo que quiere decir la frase que pones de ejemplo.

Comment: Hecho @Charlie, sacado directamente del diccionario de Cambridge.

Comment: Por si acaso, tened en cuenta que la palabra inglesa *sympathy* no es equivalente a la española *simpatía*. En castellano, tal vez la mejor traducción sería *afinidad*.

Comment: En cuanto a *relatable*, no se me ocurre ninguna palabra para traducirla. Creo que en castellano usaríamos una construcción diferente para expresar que es fácil *identificarse con* eso que en inglés decimos que es *relatable*.

Comment: burdamente seria "relacionable"

Comment: Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30824/9385

Answer (score 4):

Como se ha dicho en los comentarios, parece que el castellano no tiene un adjetivo que se corresponda más o menos exactamente con *relatable*, y es necesario usar una construcción subordinada para expresar esta idea.

En inglés, *"X is relatable"* se traduciría, por ejemplo y según el contexto, como

1. *X es algo con lo cual es posible identificarse.*
2. *Es fácil empatizar con X.*
3. *X es de tal manera que mucha gente puede entender la situación.*

Es decir, traducimos *relatable* como susceptible de fácil identificación, empatía o entendimiento (quizá se pueda también traducir haciendo referencia a la intuición: *X es intuitivamente comprensible*).

Otra posibilidad, menos exacta, sería traducir *relatable* como "familiar" o "conocido".

Comment: ¿Podría usarse la palabra **empatía** para algunos contextos?

Comment: @alvalongo Sí, claro. El verbo *empatizar* de hecho es más formal. *X is relatable*  = *Se puede sentir empatía con la situación X*.

Answer (score 0):

> If you've ever really listened to Colbie Caillat lyrics, then you know
>   they are simple, yet extremely *relatable*.

**relevantes**

the implication being that they are relevant for *me*, the person making the comment.  *La letra es sencilla pero súper relevante.*

It's not an exact equivalent but I think it's functionally equivalent.

> One of the reasons for her success is that the characters in her books are so relatable.

As to whether this is a false friend -- maybe it used to be, and maybe it still is among purists -- but here's an [example](https://www.elpaisonline.com/index.php/editorial/item/188365-smells-like-teen-spirit-la-cancion-relevante) from a newspaper in Spain of it being used with that meaning:

> La canción de Nirvana, *Smells Like Teen Spirit*, fue elegida como el tema más relevante e icónico de la historia tras un estudio realizado por Universidad de Goldsmiths.

**simpáticos**

Again, when you look at the two words side by side, you wouldn't be tempted to put an equals sign -- but I think the functions fit well with each other. *Los personajes en sus libros son simpáticos.*  Meaning, I, the person making the comment, feel comfortable and drawn to the characters.  I'm looking for a natural way to express the *feeling* of each sentence, in a natural way, as I would do when talking with a friend.

Comment: I have to differ there; Sp. *relevante* is not equivalent to Eng. *relevant*. The latter includes the idea of "having relation or applicability to the matter at hand" (cf *[relevance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relevance)*); the former only means "important, significant" and is more often used meaning "outstanding".

Comment: @pablodf76 - I thought maybe this was bilingual sloppiness on my part, or Mexico being more subject to English influences, but checking online it seems it's a pretty common usage now.

Comment: Common usage rules, of course. But it may be, as you say, a Mexican thing (that gets carried off by Mexican dubbing of English-spoken films). To me *relevante* in that meaning sounds distinctly like an anglicism (as in, one only sees it in places where it must have been the translation of English *relevant*).

Comment: @pablodf76 - Maybe.  But *El País*?  That made me wonder.  Ah -- I see a question forming.