# ¿Cómo traducir/usar "Relatable" en español?

Tags: traducción, adjetivos

Tal vez esta pregunta esta muy relacionada con la siguiente:
[Traducción al español de "Relatable"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/30472/traducci%c3%b3n-al-espa%c3%b1ol-de-relatable), pero lo que estoy buscando es de qué manera se podría intercambiar o expresar de manera concisa dentro de una narrativa.

Por ejemplo:

> Expressing this type of feelings is more relatable than the ones you described.
>
> Remember how you felt when you crossed the limit? I can relate to that!

Comment: Hace poco me pasó una cosa parecida en el sitio de inglés, que hice una pregunta que trataba de ampliar un poco otra pregunta que ya se había hecho. Acabó siendo cerrada y me sugirieron que o bien editara la pregunta original (o incluso la respuesta), o bien pusiera una recompensa en la otra pregunta explicando la información que busco. Si haces eso, todo lo relacionado con "relatable" estará en un único sitio y la gente no tendrá que navegar por varias preguntas. Siguiendo esa filosofía tal vez sea recomendable que hagas lo mismo en este caso.

Answer (score 0):

I will edit the first example to make it more *relatable*.

But what do you mean by "cross the limit"?  Is crossing the limit a good thing or a bad thing?

> This type of emotion is more relatable than the ones described in the article.

**consistente con mis experiencias**

**relevante [a mis experiencias]**

> Remember how you felt when you crossed the limit? I can relate to that!

**está vinculado a mi experiencia**

**viene muy al caso [para mí]**

Have you already taken a look at what [linguee.com has to offer](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=relatable)?  There we see that each context is different, and results in a different assortment of words.

---

**Edit**: Bottom line, each expression containing *relate* or *relatable* is best looked at as an individual case.  This isn't a simple situation like *comprar*, which has two simple words to choose from, *buy* or *purchase*, where one of them is clearly more formal than the other, *sanseacabó*.

Side note, of the four suggestions I offered here for the specific sample sentences you provided, my personal favorite -- but this might be a mexicanism -- is

- **Viene muy al caso**

but it's important to be clear that this is not a universal translation of sentences containing *relatable* or *relate*.  It won't be the best choice for all such sentences.

Answer (score 0):

No soy muy partidario de traducir las frases palabra por palabra, sino adaptarlas con expresiones cotidianas que no suenen forzadas. Una vez dicho esto, y suponiendo que yo por fin he conseguido entender lo que significa *relatable*, propondría las siguientes frases:

> Expressing this type of feelings is more relatable than the ones you described.
>   ***La gente te va a entender mejor si expresas esta clase de sentimientos, más que los que expresaste antes.***
>
> Remember how you felt when you crossed the limit? I can relate to that!
>   ***¿Recuerdas cómo te sentiste cuando cruzaste los límites? ¡Pues con eso me puedo identificar!***